# How do I find the names of USB devices in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, usb

I'm trying to figure out how to find the names of USB devices and put it in a data table on a VB.NET form.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know what to do because I don't have very good knowledge of how to use VB.NET.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: _I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know what to do because I don't have very good knowledge of how to use VB.NET_: The first step is going to be to increase your _knowledge_ of VB.NET. Unfortunately, there's just no way around this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()` to obtain the list of connected drives. Then, you can determine if a specific drive is a USB drive by examining its DriveType.

For example:

```
    Dim usbDrives As New Generic.List(Of String)

    'Iterate over all the available drives
    For Each drive As System.IO.DriveInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        ' Check if is removable (USB)
        If drive.DriveType = System.IO.DriveType.Removable Then
            usbDrives.Add(drive.Name) 'Or, you can use drive.VolumeLabel
        End If
    Next
```

Now, you can display the content of `usbDrives` in your DataTable.